# springboot heartbeat excessive Loggin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Have configured Eureka Server in a Standalone mode and I have enabled Spring Security and Have couple of Clients connecting to it.
Clients are connecting with Eureka Server,When I look at Eureka Server logs I see lots of Logs being logged, like below

> 16:57:31.538 [http-nio-8846-exec-9] DEBUG
>   o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Bound request context to
>   thread:
>
> org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1a23671d 16:57:31.540
>   [http-nio-8846-exec-9] DEBUG o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter -
>   Cleared thread-bound request context:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1a23671d

What are these?

I understood from my basic knowledge these are from springboot heartbeat related logs, but unable to understand it further.

Would like to know Is that something I am missing to configure or Should I turn off logs, if turn off then how only this part.

This is a concern,as Logs file size is growing very rapidly.

Comment: It is a debug log so there is nothing excessive about it IMO. If you're not interested by that part of the stack or that particular class, change the log level accordingly.

Comment: Change the logging of package org.springframework.boot to INFO instead of DEBUG

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions.
I added below line to logback-console.xml.

```
<logger name="org.springframework.boot.web.filter" level="INFO"/>
```